# Issues with the SSL versions used by Curl and Python SSL lib

Tags: ssl, openssl, curl

**TL;DR**
I'm trying to reach an URI which only takes SSLv3. If I try to access it with curl or Python requests (which uses the ssl module) it doesn't work (different errors).

Some longer explanation

There's this API who has this URI: https://api.mercadolibre.com/sites/MLA/search?q=ipod

1. If I try to access that URI with the browser, it works fine (Chrome and FF).
2. If I try to curl it: `curl -Iv https://api.mercadolibre.com/sites/MLA/search?q=ipod` it doesn't work. The error returned is:

   ```
   curl: (35) Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to api.mercadolibre.com:443
   ```
3. Forcing curl to use SSLv3 works fine:

   ```
   curl --sslv3 -Iv https://api.mercadolibre.com/sites/MLA/search?q=ipod
   ```
4. `openssl s_client -connect api.mercadolibre.com:443`

   answers with:

   ```
   CONNECTED(00000003)
   write:errno=104
   ---
   no peer certificate available
   ---
   No client certificate CA names sent
   ---
   SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 305 bytes
   ---
   New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
   Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
   Compression: NONE
   Expansion: NONE
   ---
   ```

How can it be possible that the browser is connecting Ok and curl and Python are not? How should I fix this? Is this even my problem (or the owner of the API)?

**Info about my system**

- Ubuntu 14.04
- OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014

Comment: [That site's SSL setup is horribly broken.](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=api.mercadolibre.com&hideResults=on) They need to fix it as soon as possible.

Comment: Well. That's a relief. But, does it has anything to do with my issue?

Comment: Most likely. As you can see, many _browsers_ would be unable to connect to it at all. The same is true of non-browser user agents such as curl. Not to mention the encryption is so weak that my sister could break it.

Comment: Reading the "Handshake Simulation" section on that report seems like "OpenSSL 1.0.1h" fails with "Protocol or cipher suite mismatch".

Comment: Yeah. Thank you very much Michael. I know someone there, I'll ping them. Do you want to create an answer for posterity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the time this question was asked, the site in question supported *only* a small selection of very weak cipher suites and had very little compatibility with modern user agents. Thus it was impossible for most browsers or even robots to negotiate a connection, let alone a secure one.

The site has been (mostly) fixed since; while it still has weak cipher suites and other problems, it should at least be functional.

Comment: Yes. True. I reported it at the time and they fixed it. Your answer provides a great summary of the issue. Thanks!